# How to limit user's permission on the data in the database?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm currently creating an attendance database for school. In the database, there are 3 categories which is `admin`,`teacher`,`parent`. I already differentiate them by adding a `column` named `category` which has the `admin`,`teacher`,`parent` in the column.

These are their permission:

`admin` : view, update, edit, delete - which means they can do whatever they wanted to do to the records.

`teacher` : view, update - `teacher` can only view the students record and take their attendance.

`parent` : view - only can see their child attendance record.

My problem right now is, how to differentiate their permission? Means, how to do *that*?

I would like to enforce this permission in the form of `mysql` 'command'. They're connected to this database by a webpage which is in form of `php` and `html`. No, they don't have the access directly to the `DB`because they can only see the data by using the webpage not by `phpMyAdmin`

If you have any link/suggestion, please do so.

Thanks.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Comment: You'll probably want to clarify for yourself where to enforce these permissions. From your current questions it's unclear if there is an application layer above the database or not. If there is, then most likely you'd enforce these permissions there and not in the database. But this depends on your overall architecture and requirements.

Comment: These people don't access the DB directly, do they? I don't see the parents typing SQL queries. I imagine you have some kind of application as the UI for these users. Also, I don't think you can grant or deny access to specific rows in a table on a DB level. This would lead me to think you have to manage these privileges on the application level. To get help on that you'd need to specify what language are you using in that application.

Comment: I already edited my questions. [tag:pinxto] and @MarcCompte

Comment: This is a bit broad, for an answer, but basically what you'd do is have a login system in your PHP page. This should let you know who is logged and then you can allow/deny access in your PHP to different views according to their role. You can also use SQL to pick only the records you want to show to a particular user (i.e. `SELECT * FROM student where parent = {logged_user_id}`). https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_mysql_login.htm and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_mysql.htm may be of help.